# How to set attribute of canvas in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a javascript DOM object and I am trying to add border to a canvas object. I use the following code:

```
canvasBorder = "thin solid black";
canvas.setAttribute("border", canvasBorder);
```

This does not work. However, when I use

```
canvas.style.border = "thin solid black";
```

It seems to work.
I have tried many options for border including permutations with only color, width (thin, 2px, 2, etc), etc. But I get the same result. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Seems you already get what is wrong (first version) and what it should be (second version). What can we do for you today?

Comment: I wanted to know how to use setAttribute properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the attribute on `canvas.style`, not `canvas`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such attribute `border` for any element. `border` is the property of `style` of the element. Its not valid attribute You can set `border` attribute using `setAttribute` and it will be added to `<canvas>` but it will not work as `style.border`
According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_canvas.asp)
There no attribute named `display` for `<canvas>`

Comment: Actually... <img> and <table> had such a `border` attribute in HTML4 and below. For compatibilty, HTML5 compliant browsers still do accept this attribute and expose an IDL property, even though it's been deprecated in favor of CSS border. HTMLCanvasElement, introduced by HTML5 however never had such an attribute. Oh and beware, W3School **is not W3C**.

Answer (score 0):

To add a border, use the `style` attribute instead of `canvas.style.border`

```
canvas.style = "border:thin solid black";
```